# OGR Resetting SetAttributeFilter and SetSpatialFilter

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

This is more of a behavior question about OGR. When I set the spatial and attribute filters like so:

```py
    self.ogr_layer.SetSpatialFilter(clip_geom)
    self.ogr_layer.SetAttributeFilter("MyField = 'some value")
```

How do I UNset these filters if I want to loop over the features again? I'm [looking for clues in the docs](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html#ResetReading) but can't quite figure it out.

Do I need to close and re-open the `ogr.Layer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested and you could reset the attribute filter in OGR (and I presume the spatial filter works the same way) using a another filter but with a blank string:

```
self.ogr_layer.SetAttributeFilter("")
```

This will produce the same output as "SELECT * FROM your_lyr" SQL statement, and in combination with self.ogr_layer.ResetReading() should leave you where you want before looping your features again.